# When the mongodb database connection is closed using sails.js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sails.js

I am using sails-mongo .

MongoLocal: {

```
module: 'sails-mongo',
host: 'localhost',
port : '27017',
user: '',
password: '', 
database: 'test'
```

}

I would like to know when is the sails.js closing the connections for mongodb ?

For eg : Currently , if i have 10models , total connections is about 70-90 connections.
How can i make it only one connection per one application instance?

Please help. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I found there's a **poolSize** in the configuration of `sails-mongo` [here](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-mongo/blob/master/lib/connection.js#L100) and the `sails-mongo` is using [Mongo native client](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/1.4/driver-articles/mongoclient.html#mongoclient-connect-options) which has a key **maxPoolSize**.
Haven't tried it but maybe its something you're looking for

```
{
    module: 'sails-mongo',
    host: 'localhost',
    port : '27017',
    user: '',
    password: '', 
    database: 'test',
    maxPoolSize: 1,
    poolSize: 1
}
```